# Rectangles don't show in the image when using cv2.rectangle() in streamlit web app

Tags: python, opencv, drawrectangle, streamlit

I am trying to showcase my deep learning work with streamlit, which involves drawing rectangles over the objects detected in the image. However no rectangles can be seen on it. So what's wrong with it?[image]

Here's the code snippet:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(32, 16))
    for box in boxes:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = box
        cv2.rectangle(img=sample,
                      pt1=(y1, x1),
                      pt2=(y2, x2),
                      color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=3)
    ax.set_axis_off()
    im = ax.imshow(sample)
    st.pyplot()
    st.write("# Results")
    st.dataframe(pd.DataFrame(results))
```

Comment: Can you please try printing `x1, y1, x2, y2` ?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cv2.rectangle returns an image with the rectangle on it (it doesn`t do it in place). So it should be:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(32, 16))
for box in boxes:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = box
    sample = cv2.rectangle(img=sample,
                  pt1=(y1, x1),
                  pt2=(y2, x2),
                  color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=3)
ax.set_axis_off()
im = ax.imshow(sample)
st.pyplot()
st.write("# Results")
st.dataframe(pd.DataFrame(results))
```

Comment: I tried as well but there comes another error, saying "TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float"

Comment: what is in `sample`? (before the `cv2.rectangle`)

Comment: Solved, please refer to my modification in your codes